# Regression with all variables without explicitly declaring them

Tags: function, stata

I have a dataset that I would like to run a regression on in Stata. I want to make one of the dummy variables the base so I use the `ib1.month1` in the  `regress` command.

Is it possible to include in my regression all other variables in the dataset without explicitly writing out each variable again?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `ds` command:

```
sysuse auto, clear
drop make 

ds price foreign, not 

regress price ib1.foreign `r(varlist)' 

      Source |       SS           df       MS      Number of obs   =        69
-------------+----------------------------------   F(10, 58)       =      8.66
       Model |   345416162        10  34541616.2   Prob > F        =    0.0000
    Residual |   231380797        58  3989324.09   R-squared       =    0.5989
-------------+----------------------------------   Adj R-squared   =    0.5297
       Total |   576796959        68  8482308.22   Root MSE        =    1997.3

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
       price |      Coef.   Std. Err.      t    P>|t|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
     foreign |
   Domestic  |  -3334.848   957.2253    -3.48   0.001    -5250.943   -1418.754
         mpg |  -21.80518    77.3599    -0.28   0.779    -176.6578    133.0475
       rep78 |   184.7935   331.7921     0.56   0.580    -479.3606    848.9476
    headroom |  -635.4921   383.0243    -1.66   0.102    -1402.198    131.2142
       trunk |   71.49929   95.05012     0.75   0.455    -118.7642    261.7628
      weight |   4.521161   1.411926     3.20   0.002     1.694884    7.347438
      length |  -76.49101   40.40303    -1.89   0.063    -157.3665     4.38444
        turn |  -114.2777   123.5374    -0.93   0.359    -361.5646    133.0092
displacement |   11.54012   8.378315     1.38   0.174    -5.230896    28.31115
  gear_ratio |  -318.6479    1124.34    -0.28   0.778    -2569.259    1931.964
       _cons |   13124.34     6726.3     1.95   0.056    -339.8103     26588.5
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Note that in general, all variables cannot include any string variables. In the example here, `make` is the only string variable, so @Pearly Spencer just `drop`ped it. But note that `ds, has(type numeric)` is a filter that ignores all string variables.